# How to fix "curl: (23) Failed writing body (4096 != 9142)" in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I'm trying to run a query on my command prompt window. However, I got an error

> curl: (23) Failed writing body (4096 != 9142)

I don't understand how it happened and how to debug it. The code is:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d " { \"query\": { \"match\" : { \"body\" : { \"query\" : \"cat\"} } } }"
```

However, when executing the following code

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d " { \"query\": { \"match\" : { \"body\" : { \"query\" : \"cats\"} } } }"
```

There's no error message.

Comment: Are you sure that it's Elasticsearch that's listening on 9200? That looks like there's a problem with whatever service is on that port; curl is having trouble writing the request body into the socket. It smells like a misconfiguration, but it's hard to say what without much more detail.

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200` ?